# Sort an array first by reverse number, then alphabetical?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array that has a numbered key, followed by a name, in this syntax:

```
[50-Aname] => arraydata
[45-Anothername] => arraydata
[45-Bname] => arraydata
[30-Cname] => arraydata
```

By using krsort(), I can get the array to sort as a high-score table (Counting backwards) . But this means, if they have the same number, Bname will appear before Anothername as it is ordering reverse alphabetically as well.

So, is there a way to sort the numbers largest to smallest, but alphabetically as well?

Comment: poor array structure, compound keys are always a bad idea.

Comment: If it's bad, could you provide an idea on how to do this another way? It would still be interesting to hear a solution for sorting an array this way, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `uksort()` and define a function as a comparator of your keys, based on which the sorting will be carried.

In short, that function should split the key by the "-" and then use the 2 components to create a total order.

The documentation of `uksort`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

Comment: Thank you, uksort put me on the right trail. I was able to create this little function:

        private function splitsort($a, $b) {

 $key1 = explode("-", $a);

 $key2 = explode("-", $b);

 if ($key1[0] != $key2[0])
     return $key2[0] - $key1[0];
 return strcmp($a, $b);
    }

Answer (score 1):

For this type problem i would put those data in database and sort it.

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY score DESC, name ASC");
```

Comment: Good idea, But I want to limit the amount of SQL queries on the page. The data is stored as an array and i've sorted it and stepped though it a few times in other places.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ksort()` on that array structure produces what you desire. I'm running PHP v5.3.13.

```
$to_be_sorted = array(
    "50-Aname" => 123,
    "45-Bname" => 123,
    "45-Cname" => 123,
    "45-Anothername" => 123,
    "30-Cname" => 123
);

ksort($to_be_sorted);
var_dump($to_be_sorted);
```

Result:

```
array(5) {
  ["30-Cname"]=>
  int(123)
  ["45-Anothername"]=>
  int(123)
  ["45-Bname"]=>
  int(123)
  ["45-Cname"]=>
  int(123)
  ["50-Aname"]=>
  int(123)
}
```

Comment: The numbers are supposed to be in reverse order, though.

Comment: But the numbers are ordered smallest to largest in your result =)